# Transfer of my child's visa from my husband to my name

Tags: uk

I have applied for Tier 2 ICT Long Term Visa for myself and dependent visa for my daughter. I have received my visa valid till July 2019. However, my daughter's visa is valid only till 30th Aug 2017. As per the details received from UK Visa, the end date for my daughter's visa is mapped with my husband's visa end date who is already in UK and have visa till 30th Aug 2017.
Will my daughter need to come back to India on 30th Aug 2017? Is there a way I can get my daughter's visa transferred to my name?

Comment: She will need to apply for entry clearance as a dependent; but please use Expats for T2 questions, http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions Close voting.